# WndProc no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, wndproc

I am creating a custom user control and i am trying to call WndProc in that control. But, it gives me error `WndProc: no suitable method found to override.`

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl, ICloneable, IComparable<MyControl>
{
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override IntPtr WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        SOME CODES
    }
}
```

How to override this method in my usercontrol? Is it related to `partial` modifier?

Answer (score 3):

the signature is:

```
protected virtual void WndProc(ref Message m)
```

Comment: Yup, Error is gone. What is the difference between the both calls. Why do i need to call that method using virtual keyword.

Comment: not the virtual keyword is the point ... WndProc is not returning an IntPtr

Comment: You have written `virtual` keyword instead of `override`. Does it make difference?

Comment: I have tried your solution. But, it does not work. the function does not call. Should I need to call it manually?

Comment: i wrote that this is the method signature ... not the line of code you'd need ... instead of virtual, you need to mark your method as override ... and as pointed out your mistake was to give the return type as IntPtr ... the signature says void ... i suggest looking up override and virtual in the c# reference

Answer (score 0):

Just add full variable type for the `Messsage m` (`System.Windows.Forms.Message`) and pass `byref`:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
```